# Error en un boton eliminar

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Es un CRUD con entity framework y SQL, estoy haciendo el boton eliminar y aparece ese error
Necesito una solucion o una alternativa al codigo de eliminar, Los el tipo de datos de la base de datos son de tipo cadena no int.
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero la sentencia del Convert.toint32 es inútil, ya que solo conviertes y no lo guardas o utilizas, por lo que es recomendable eliminarla.

Segundo él, en el find buscas el objeto textbox no el texto que contiene y el find busca un objeto factura parecido al insertado, por lo que yo lo haría de la siguiente manera usando linq:

(Nota porque no dispongo de mucha información, he usado lo que tenía a mano y me he inventado un poco las propiedades, lo que no se podia replicar al no disponer de mucha información)

```
private void button2_Clik(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Sist_VentaEntities8 db= new Sist_VentaEntities8()) {


            Factura fACTURA = db.FACTURA.Where(x=>x.Id_facutra==textbox1.text).First(); //donde id_factura es el nombre de la propiedad  que contiene el texto buscado
            db.FACTURA.Remove(fACTURA);
            db.SaveChanges();





        }
    }
```